# Multiplying a random variable with itself

Tags: random-variables

Let $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, I want to compute $x^²$, but I only have a random variable $X$ such that with very high probability, say $1-(1/C)$ for $C > 0$, $|X-x| \leq \epsilon$ holds.

Can anything be said about the value of $X \cdot X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $|X^2-x^2|=|X-x||X+x|$. Hence if $|X-x| \leq \epsilon$ then $|X^2-x^2| \leq \epsilon(2|x|+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Thanks! So if I assume that I have an one-sided error, i.e., $X-x \leq \epsilon$, can I also just multiply $(x+\epsilon)(x+\epsilon)$. For some reason, I think I made an independence assumption...

Comment: Actually, then the situation can be more complicated because $f(x)=x^2$ is not a monotone function. If $X-x \leq \epsilon$ then $X^2-x^2=(X-x)(X+x)$. So you get an inequality comparing $X^2-x^2$ to $\epsilon(X+x)$, but the direction of the inequality depends on the sign of $X+x$, which is not necessarily determined by the given inequality. (Of course it is if $x+\epsilon<0$.)